# Read multiple *.rtf files in r

Tags: r, import, rtf

I have a folder with more than 2,000 rtf documents. I want to import them into r (preferable into a data frame that can be used in combination with the [tidytext](https://github.com/juliasilge/tidytext) package). In addition, I need an additional column, adding the filename so that I can link the content of each rtf document to the filename (later, I will also have to extract information from the filename and save it into seperate columns of my data set).

I came across a solution by [Jens Leerssen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40943207/2459401) that I tried to adapt to my requirements:

```
require(textreadr)

read_plus <- function(flnm) {
read_rtf(flnm) %>% 
    mutate(filename = flnm)
}

tbl_with_sources <-
    list.files(path= "./data", pattern = "*.rtf", 
           full.names = TRUE) %>% 
map_df(~read_plus(.))
```

However, I get the following error message:

> Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
>     no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "character"

Can anyone tell me why this error occurs or propose another solution to my problem?

Comment: The help page for `read_rtf` says the value returned is a character vector not a `data.frame` which the `mutate` line is expecting?

Comment: so how can I tell read_rtf to convert a character into a data.frame?

Comment: I'm not sure whether your documents are all the same length or what sort of `data.frame` you want them in.

Comment: Does it really matter whether the documents are of different length (they are!). I want a data.frame with two columns (filename, text) and one row per observation (=document).

Comment: Does this work swapped for the mutate line? `data.frame(filename = flnm, doc = .)`

Comment: Almost! However, for some documents, there is not one row per observation, but one row per paragraph.

Comment: sorry I can't debug that further...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem, with some workaround.

1) I converted the *.rft files to *.txt files by using the `textutil` command in the MacOSX terminal:

```
find . -name \*.rtf -print0 | xargs -0 textutil -convert txt
```

By doing so, I get also rid of formatting.

2) I then used the `read_plus` function of Jens Lerrssen. However I now use `read.delim` instead of `read_rtf` and included two options (`stringsAsFactors` and `quote`) to get rid of warnings and/or errors:

```
read_plus <- function(flnm) {
    read.delim(flnm, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, quote = "") %>% 
            mutate(filename = flnm)
}
```

3) Finally, I read in all the *.txt files and renamed the columnn `V1` at the end.

```
df <- list.files(path = "./data", pattern = "*.txt", 
               full.names = TRUE) %>% 
    map_df(~read_plus(.)) %>%
    rename(paragraph = V1)
```