# How to test for existence of certain column names across numerous CSVs

Tags: r, string, csv, merge, names

I have about 60 `csv` files that I want to merge. One challenge is inconsistent naming of columns, although *essentially* all files (should) have same data.

To deal with this issue, I would like to first test which files have *certain* column names (and which don't). I have a vector of strings, where each element reflects a column name, to be checked whether it exists in each csv file.

I'm trying to achieve a dataframe that will have:

- **columns**: each column corresponds to a column name I'm looking to test whether exists
- **rows**: each row corresponds to one csv file
- **values**: in each cell, either `0` or `1` to mark whether the csv file has the column name

### 3 CSVs for example

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_1 <-
  tribble(~ date, ~ name, ~ age, ~ gender,
        "2020-11-29", "sarah", 43, "female")

df_2 <-
  tribble(~ createdAt, ~ person, ~ age, ~ is_female,
        "2020-10-10", "bob", 25, 0)

df_3 <- 
  tribble(~ date, ~ name, ~ age_value, ~ gender,
        "2010-01-07", "wendy", 70, "female")
```

```r
write_csv(df_1, "csv_1.csv")
write_csv(df_2, "csv_2.csv")
write_csv(df_3, "csv_3.csv")
```

#### Vector with names

Now let's say that I'm ignorant of the column names in the 3 CSVs created above. *I believe* that each CSV should have column names of *either* `date`, `name`, `age`, `age_value`, `gender`.

```r
col_names_to_test <-
  c(
    "date",
    "name",
    "age",
    "age_value",
    "gender"
  )
```

### A basis for the solution

This is just my direction, based on [this nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50021563/6105259) that defines a reading & editing function, then uses `list.files` with `purrr::map_df` on the function defined.

```r
read_plus <- 
  function(flnm) {
  read_csv(flnm, col_types = cols(.default = "c")) # %>%
  ## here some testing against the vector `col_names_to_test` ?
  }

tbl_with_sources <-
   list.files(path = //folder-with-csv-files,
              pattern = "*.csv", 
              full.names = TRUE,
              recursive = TRUE) %>% 
  map_df(~ read_plus(.))
```

This is just a general idea... I'm used to tidyverse approaches but I'll be happy with any solution.

#### Desired Output

```r
  filename  date  name   age age_value gender
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1 csv_1        1     1     1         0      1
2 csv_2        0     0     1         0      0
3 csv_3        1     0     0         1      1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a function `ok` which given file name `f` returns a named 0/1 vector having the same length as `col_names_to_test` having a 1 if the corresponding component of `col_names_to_test` exists as a column name in that file and 0 otherwise.  Then define a vector of file names `files`.  Give it names without the extension and apply `ok` to it using `map_dfr`.

This is reasonably compact and only uses purrr.

```
library(purrr)

ok <- function(f) +setNames(col_names_to_test %in% names(read.csv(f)), col_names_to_test)
files <- Sys.glob("csv_*.csv")
shortnames <- sub("\\.csv$", "", basename(files))
files %>% setNames(shortnames) %>% map_dfr(ok, .id = "file")
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  file   date  name   age age_value gender
  <chr> <int> <int> <int>     <int>  <int>
1 csv_1     1     1     1         0      1
2 csv_2     0     0     1         0      0
3 csv_3     1     1     0         1      1
```

### Update

Have completely revised.

Comment: awesome. I'll just add that in my case, I assign `files` with `files <- list.files(path = //folder-with-csv-files, pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)`.

Comment: also, would you mind explaining the role of `+` before `setNames` in the function `ok`?

Comment: That converts the logical vector to a 0/1 vector.  Try `+ c(TRUE, FALSE)`

Comment: Also have added shortnames line to the solution which handles full path names.

Comment: I have another question that I wonder if requires a separate post or can be added here -- is it simple enough to tweak `ok` function (or create `ok_2` instead) so that it will return `1` for *partial matching* too? For example, if `col_names_to_test` has `age`, and `csv_3` has `age_value`, we will consider this a match because `age_value` contains `age` as a substring. This will be useful in cases where we don't know the exact wording for column names across CSVs, but can guesstimate that "age" columns are likely to have `age` at least as a substring.

Comment: Look at `?grepl`

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the index of columns matching `col_names_to_test`, you can use this approach:

```
library('data.table')
library('dplyr')

col_names_to_test = c('date', 'name', 'age', 'age_value', 'gender')

# define columns indexes matching the pattern
DefCols = function(input_path, patterns) {
  pattern = patterns %>%
    str_flatten('|')
  cols = input_path %>%
    fread(nrows = 1) %>%
    colnames() %>%
    str_which(pattern)
  return(cols)
}

# define the input directory
input_dir = ''

cols = input_dir %>%
  dir(pattern = '.*.csv$', full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE) %>%
  lapply(DefCols, col_names_to_test)
```

However, if you also want to load the dataframes with only the matching columns, you can extend it, as follows:

```
library('data.table')
library('dplyr')

col_names_to_test = c('date', 'name', 'age', 'age_value', 'gender')

# define columns indexes matching the pattern
LoadDF = function(input_path, patterns) {
  pattern = patterns %>%
    str_flatten('|')
  cols = input_path %>%
    fread(nrows = 1) %>%
    colnames() %>%
    str_which(pattern)
  df = input_path %>%
    fread(drop = -cols) %>%
    as.data.frame()
  return(df)
}

# define the input directory
input_dir = ''

dfs = 'input_dir' %>%
  dir(pattern = '.*.csv$', full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE) %>%
  lapply(LoadDF, col_names_to_test)
```

Note: when I'm loading the data to check the column names, I keep only the first row (`nrows = 1`), because I don't care about the values in each cell.